# How to have Auto Layout set up a grid of icons proportionally for each device

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, xcode8

I am coming across a few issues with Auto Layout when I set up my storyboard.

[image: I would like my app to be setup as displayed in this picture.]

I want my app display to be identical (image size, spacing, proportions) on each generation of iPhone.

I have somewhat achieved the results that I want by setting each `UIImageView` to have central Autoresizing and an Aspect Fit Content Mode; however I cannot get the same results once I place the `UIImageViews` into `Stack Views` which I have been lead to believe is the proper way to set up this 4x4 icon grid.

Any help is greatly appreciated and if any clarification is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Views are here to simplify things.

You need 4 *horizontal* Stack Views inside 1 *vertical* Stack View.

Then, you need only 4 constraints in the vertical (main) Stack View: Left, Right, Bottom and Aspect Ratio (1:1).

The Stack View configurations are all the same: Fill and Fill Equally.
In my example I also added a space of 10 to each Stack View.

Like this:

[image: Xcode setup]

> Bonus: notice that I'm not using `UIImageViews`, but custom `UIViews`,
>   which draw themselves at runtime. You can even live-preview then in
>   Xcode via `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`.

---

**Results**

iPhone SE:

[image]

iPhone 6:

[image]

iPhone 7 Plus:

[image]

Take a look at the code:

> [git clone git@github.com:backslash-f/grid-on-stackview.git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxDs.png)

(Please give `Stack Views` a chance. :-))

Answer (score 0):

If the above gives you difficulty, which will not be the case, you can use a container view AutoLayout pinned to the 3 edges. Then place a https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview in the container view and set up the collection view with your data source. This is how I solved this problem in the past. Be sure to shut off the scroll, bounce, and control the amount of data source items to perfectly fit the numbers of the grid.

Comment: Although a collection view would work, it's overkill. The easiest and recommended way is to use Stack Views. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/